# modify T-SQL to get results

Tags: t-sql

I am an amateur.

I am trying the following

```
select * from [dbo].[AccessFeeDetail]
where LastLoginDate >= '10/15/2012 00:00:00.000', jobname not like 'Uptest_%'
```

I am making a mistake on where clause. Can you correct me

"LastLoginDate" and "JobName" are Fields in the same table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comma `,` is not a valid logical operator. Try using `AND` or `OR`, depending on what you need, rows that match either one or both criteria (use `OR`) or only the rows that match both criteria (use `AND`).

You should also avoid writing dates with ambiguous formats, like the `'10/15/2012 00:00:00.000'`. Use either `2012-10-15T00:00:00.000` or `'20121015 00:00:00.000'` format. You can read Aaron Bertrand's blog for more details about dates and range queries: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries). In this particular query and because the date has no time part, you can also use the shorter `'20121015'`:

```
select * 
from [dbo].[AccessFeeDetail]
where LastLoginDate >= '20121015'
      AND 
      jobname not like 'Uptest_%' ;
```